# MDS is not working

Tags: blackberry, mds-cs

I am facing problem with MDS-CS simulator coming with JDE 4.7.0 , i am not able to connect to internet . I went in edit->preferences->simulator tab ->general tab -> ticked Launch MDS-CS  with simulator check box. when i debug application i got the error, Here is following link which states the  error.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?3e41fce0ee.jpg

2) I have experience in symbian development  , am new to Blackberry. In symbian there is called RDA (remote device access) which gives device kind of environment if we don't have device. Is same kind of concept available in blackberry as i don't have touch screen device
to test application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like wrong path to MDS, or antivirus/firewall activity.
   Try download [standalone MDS simulator](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/), install it and run before run device simulator.
   If you have antivirus/firewall installed, check it's logs.

**EDIT** Also see [Support - BlackBerry MDS Simulator does not launch](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800792/801079/Support_-_BlackBerry_Mobile_Data_Service_Simulator_does_not_launch.html?nodeid=800979&vernum=0)

2. AFAIK, RIM has no RDA like service..